# Copying from vector of derived class to vector of base class

Tags: c++, stl

I am looking for the simplest way to copy a vector of a derived class to a vector of a base class without doing it element by element. How can I fix the following to get this to work?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A( int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

struct B : public A {
    B (int a, int b) : A (a), b(b) {}
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<B> vb { B{1,2}, B{3,4}};
    std::vector<A> va = vb;
    for (const auto& item : va) {
        std::cout << item.a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Right now I get the following error message from g++

```
error: conversion from ‘vector<B>’ to non-scalar type ‘vector<A>’ requested
   16 |     std::vector<A> va = vb;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<A>` can't be converted from `std::vector<B>` directly, they're two independent types substantially.

You can initialize `va` with the iterators of `vb`.

```
std::vector<A> va { vb.begin(), vb.end() };
```

Note that the elements of `va` would be slice-copied.

Comment: Interesting. How is it possible converting automatically without struct A construct such as A(const B& b) : a(b.a) { } ?

Comment: @DDukDDak99 `A` has the copy constructor taking `const A&`, and a `B` could be bound to `const A&`, since it's derived class of `A`. As the result `B` could be converted (slice-copied) to `A` implicitly (via `A`'s copy constructor).

Comment: Oh. Right. I forgot struct B is derived.

Comment: Initially I though inheritance would allow some short-cuts but is probably more trouble than it is worth. I have therefore posted an answer which uses composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer composition over inheritance, you can use:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    A a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<B> vb { {1 ,2},{3, 4} };
    std::vector<A> va;
    std::transform(vb.begin(), vb.end(), std::back_inserter(va), 
            [](const B& b) -> A { return b.a; } );
    for (const auto& item : va) {
        std::cout << item.a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though lambdas are cool, I prefer `std::mem_fn(&B::a)` in a case like this because it is shorter and more versatile.